# How to change QuoteItem BaseCost in Magento?

Tags: magento

We have a Magento shop with various products but the price depends on the selection of the customer and is dynamically calculated. I can add the dynamically calculated custom price in our Observer with event checkout_cart_product_add_after like this:

```
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($calculatedPrice);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($calculatedPrice);
$quoteItem->setBaseCost($calculatedBaseCost); // does nothing
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quoteItem->save();
```

But I also want to change the base_cost (which is originally 0.00) to my calculated base_cost. But what ever I try, it just won't change.

I have now added a custom column but I would rather make use of that base_cost to see everything in sales reports.
Why can't I change the base_cost? Anybody any idea how to get this working? Thank you very much in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same problem. I've found the base_cost is set at first, but somewhere later in the request it is removed again.

I've run a stack trace to see when & where it becomes empty. This is the trace;

```
2015-05-14T10:24:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): [ 0] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php:652 Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item->save()
[ 1] app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:340                          Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->save()
[ 2] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:319                        Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_afterSave()
[ 3] app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:1966                         Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
[ 4] app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php:459                        Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->save()
[ 5] app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php:461        Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
[ 6] app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php:432        Mage_Checkout_CartController->_updateShoppingCart()
[ 7] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:418              Mage_Checkout_CartController->updatePostAction()
[ 8] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250     Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('updatePost')
[ 9] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:172               Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)
[10] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354                             Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
[11] app/Mage.php:684                                                      Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
[12] app/Mage.php:684                                                      Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
```

It appears it is in the CartController. When you look at the indexAction() in the CartController, you'll see that the cart gets initialized through init() and then saved through save(). This save() call actually removes the base_cost for some reason. I can't find why or where though. This is kinda where my search ends.

When the save() call is commented out, as far as the cart page is concerned, this works. But as soon as you try to place the order, the base_cost is removed again. I'm resorting to a custom column now too but I'd like to believe there is a better way.

Comment: Hi Peter Jaap, you may want to have a look at setProduct in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item. Extending it solved our problem partially but in the end it was decided on a special attribute for this purpose. But I do think it could have worked.

Comment: I've now added a custom attribute but that value also disappears. Also, there is nothing interesting in setProduct(). It just sets the base cost from the product, but this function is ran before my function where I overwrite this value.

Comment: Ok, after clearing the cache the custom attribute did work ;-)

Comment: I've also added an observer on sales_order_place_after that copies the value from my custom column to the base_cost column for the sales_flat_order_item table so the reports in the backend show correct values.

Answer (score 0):

A more suitable event would be `catalog_product_get_final_price`. You have the product as a parameter there with all custom options etc. and can set the final price (or other atributes if you must). I'm not sure about the behavior of `base_cost` but would expect less trouble when using this event.